# Pattern matching error in Scheme

Tags: syntax, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I have written a function `match-rewriter` that is just `match-lambda` except that it returns its argument if no match is found.  `match-rewriter` is part of a larger function.  Here is a portion of the code:

```
((match-rewriter

   (`(PARAMS: (,<arg>))
    `(Success))

   (`(,<func> . ,<args>)
    `(Failure))

   )ls)
```

This function call:

```
(annotate '(PARAMS: (y))
```

returns Failure

In another post someone pointed out that this works:

```
#lang racket

(match `(PARAMS: (y))
  [`(PARAMS: (,var)) 'yep]
  [otherise 'nope])
```

returning yep

I verified that it works but I can't figure out why the same pattern isn't being matched in `match-rewriter`.

Strangely, if I just run this code manually substituting '(PARAMS: (y)) for "ls" it works.  Which really confuses me.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of `match-rewriter`?  How does `annotate` use `match-rewriter`?  I.e., is the first code sample what actually gets run by the second one?

Comment: Based on the last part of your question (after your most recent edit), there is probably a bug in `match-rewriter`.  Why not just replace `(match-rewriter ...)` with `(match-lambda ... (x x))`?

Comment: Ah, the problem is solved.  The '(PARAMS: (y)) was actually matching an earlier pattern that was referring it recursively to the later pattern.  Moving the rule up in the code fixed the problem.  Thanks for the comments.